Visiting dynamic website and clicking on arrows to expand and then select elements to load the page contents using Python
I am nope in python. I want python to visit this site https://icd.who.int/browse10/2019/en , and click on (arrows to expand them) which are located on this
//tr[@class='ygtvrow']//td[starts-with(@id, 'ygtvt') and (contains(@class, 'ygtvcell ygtvtm') or contains(@class, 'ygtvcell ygtvtp') or contains(@class, 'ygtvcell ygtvlm'))]

If you visit the website you will see each arrow is nested inside another. But I when I inspect the html of it in google chrome and press ctrl+f and paste the above XPATH it was able to find them all and navigate through them. Also after python clicked and expanded all the arrows, I want it to select each element found here
//tr[@class='ygtvrow']//td[@class='ygtvcell ygtvhtml ygtvcontent']

to load its page content. It will be better if this happen sequentially.
I appreciate any help.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Setup Selenium with ChromeDriver using ChromeDriverManager
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run in headless mode for faster execution

# Install and set up ChromeDriver
service = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Open the URL
driver.get('https://icd.who.int/browse10/2019/en')

# Define a wait to handle dynamic loading
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Function to click elements based on the provided XPath
def click_elements(xpath):
    try:
        elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        for element in elements:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error clicking elements: {e}")

# Start with the first element and expand subsequent ones
start_xpath = "//td[@id='ygtvt2' and (contains(@class, 'ygtvcell ygtvtm') or contains(@class, 'ygtvcell ygtvtp') or contains(@class, 'ygtvcell ygtvlm'))]//a[@class='ygtvspacer']"
click_elements(start_xpath)

# Expand dynamically loaded elements based on their parent element being clicked
next_xpaths = [
    "//td[@id='ygtvt24' and (contains(@class, 'ygtvcell ygtvtm') or contains(@class, 'ygtvcell ygtvtp') or contains(@class, 'ygtvcell ygtvlm'))]//a[@class='ygtvspacer']",
    "//td[@id='ygtvt45' and (contains(@class, 'ygtvcell ygtvtm') or contains(@class, 'ygtvcell ygtvtp') or contains(@class, 'ygtvcell ygtvlm'))]//a[@class='ygtvspacer']"
]

for xpath in next_xpaths:
    click_elements(xpath)

# Optionally, capture the page content after expansion
page_content = driver.page_source

# Close the driver
driver.quit()

# Print the page content or handle as needed
print(page_content)```


maybe first check what you have in driver.page_source (or run browser without "--headless" to use DevTools to see what you have in HTML) because server may sends different values in classes for different users, different devices, or different session - to stop scrapers like you :)

other idea: first try simpler xpath - like td[@id='ygtvt24'] - and display class for every element which match to this xpath -and you will see if classes have expected values.

did you tried to use only contains(@class, 'ygtvcell') without ygtvtm, ygtvtm, etc.?

other suggestion. Selenium gives references to objects in browser memory and when you click something (or you load new page) then it may move object in new places in memory and references may not work. Sometimes it need to use find() again.

other suggestion. Maybe first run code without try/except to see full error message - maybe there is different problem but you can see it because it doesn't display full error message

it seems this page has API - so maybe you could get it all without using Selenium. It could be much simpler.

Thank you Furas. Your suggestion to use only contains(@class, 'ygtvcell') without ygtvtm, ygtvtm seemed working (with help of AI). However I wan the loop to break once it came across  U85. How do I achieve that? Also, it is only expanding the arrows without loading the page content, which in this case python is unable to scrap the "icode" text from it?
I appreciate your support! and thanks in advance

if <a class="ygtvlabel " data-id="U85"> is inside one of element then you can use relative xpath (which starts with dot) to search only in element element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a[@data-id="U85"]') and you would have to run it inside for-loop to check every element

Is there something specific you want to pull from the site? Selenium may be over kill here

I found a locator for all collapsed arrows, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.ygtvtp > a.ygtvspacer"). The code below clicks through a group of them, searches for more, and repeats until there are no more to click.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://icd.who.int/browse10/2019/en'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.ygtvtp > a.ygtvspacer")
arrows = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(locator))
while arrows:
    for arrow in arrows:
        arrow.click()
    arrows = driver.find_elements(*locator)

NOTE: There are a LOT of collapsed arrows so this takes a while to complete.

Thank you. I like how fast it opens the arrows, however, it missed few of them in each chapter!
